# Div background color overlaps other div, but content doesn't

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I've never seen this before

I'm working on a basic blog website now I have created the page and I'm adding a DIV container to use for a newsletter subscription. What I found out though is that when I check my code everything is where it is supposed to be except my newsletter div (.newsletter-container) for some odd reason the div itself places itself above another div but when I type in text then the text comes below that div. I'm quite confused by it and don't really know how to explain it.

I'd say take a look at it yourself in the appended codepen to understand what I mean. The yellowish color is my actual div and as you can see next to pagenation it shows the content of that div. But both the background-color and the content has to be placed below the pagenation

Thanks in advance and please tell me what I did wrong as I haven't build a website in a while.

My code: [codepen](https://codepen.io/tom-truyen/pen/qBEyQoq)

Code of the newsletter:

```css
.newsletter-container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(252, 250, 238, 1);
  /* padding: 50px 0px; */
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="newsletter-container">CONTENT OF NEWSLETTER</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In container above ( your pagination ), there is a lot of `float: left` elements if you add to `.newsletter-container` class :

```
clear: both; // or left
```

The container will be in next line.

Is this what you wanted to achive ?